# HTML: <textarea>-Tag: How to correctly escape HTML and JavaScript content displayed in there?

Tags: html, textarea

I have a HTML Tag `<textarea>$FOO</textarea>` and the `$FOO` Variable will be filled with arbitrary HTML and JavaScript Content, to be displayed and edited within the textarea. What kind of "escaping" do I neet to apply to $FOO?

I first tought of escaping it HTML but this didnt work (as I will then get shown not the original HTML Code of $FOO but rather the escaped content. This is of course not what I want: I want to be displayed the unescaped HTML/JS Content of the variable...

Is it impossible to display HTML Content within a `<textarea>` tag and also allow it to be editable as full HTML?

thanks
jens

Comment: This was my fault: The problem was the content got escaped TWO times.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I first tought of escaping it HTML

Yes, that's right. The contents of a `<textarea>` are no different from the contents of any other element like a `<span>` or a `<p>`: if you want to put some text inside you must HTML-escape any `<` or `&` characters in it to `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively.

Browsers do tend to give you more leeway with fault markup in `<textarea>`​s, in that the fallback for invalid unescaped `<` symbols is to render them as text instead of tags, but that doesn't make it any less wrong or dangerous (for XSS).

> but this didnt work

Please post what you did that didn't work. HTML-escaping is definitely the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use "Commons Velocity" that internally uses some other Apache's StringUtils library for HTML Encoding. I have to dig deeper it seems that somewhere theres then something going wrong: <!-- test --> gives me &lt;!-- test --&gt; This means theres something double escaped. Thanks for your answer then I know I have to resarch further how to escape it.

Comment: Maybe check to see if an `EscapeHtmlReference` ReferenceInsertionEventHandler has been set up in Velocity. If so, you wouldn't need to do any more escaping.

Comment: @bobince - I have similar questions with using the PageDown editor/sanitizer. Would you mind taking a look? In the context of MVC3 I cannot seem to find the proper method for encoding my TextArea content before it posted back to the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073132/request-validation-when-posting-html-javascript-content-mvc3, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071369/handling-code-blocks-with-markdown-pagedown

Comment: @one: see answer on the latter question; I don't think you're having any problem with encoding your textarea, you're just being bitten by the lamentable uselessness that is Request Validation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the special character of HTML with [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3) (either numerical character references or entity references), in `textarea`, at least `&`, `<` and `>`.

Comment: hello Gumbo, Thanks for your help!!! It seems the problem then must be that the escaping libraries do not correctly work as they should. thanks.