# Handling Code Blocks with Markdown (Pagedown)

Tags: javascript, html, security, post, markdown

I'm betting I'm using something incorrectly here...

My MVC3 application uses [Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) to provide a javascript text editor, markdown converter, and live preview. I use its "santizer" object to strip potentially dangerous code just as suggested in instruction - you can see it at work in the [demo](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html).

The javascript code looks like this:

```
(function () {
    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
    editor1.run();
})();
```

This code transforms a marked `textarea` tag into an editor, and uses the santizing converter to strip bad stuff. In some ways it seems to be working. Examples:

- `marquee` tag as in the demo it is stripped properly.
- `<p style="font-size:40em;">Super Big Text</p>` is stripped to `Super Big Text`

But something is not correct... when I insert a fake javascript like so:

```
TEXT `<script type="text/javascript">alert("gotcha!");</script>` MORE TEXT
```

and post the form, it bombs out with a yellow screen of death:

`Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value, and processing of the request has been aborted.`

Is this string not already encoded safely like `&lgt;script`... etc.?

**Question:** What am I missing to ensure code blocks and inline code are properly transformed so that they may be posted to the server as a safe string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I missing to ensure code blocks and inline code are properly transformed so that they may be posted to the server as a safe string?

Nothing. Or at least probably nothing, assuming you're creating the textarea with the correct output escaping, which you will be if using eg a Web Forms or MVC control.

The YSOD appears for any and all input content that looks like element markup, *regardless* of whether your application handles output escaping correctly or is vulnerable. It's not indicative of an XSS problem, it happens all the time.

If you want to allow user input that contains data that looks like element markup (and there's nothing intrinsically dangerous about that—you just have to get the output escaping right), turn off Request Validation. It is **completely bogus** as a real security feature and only really gives you a false sense of security; it is disappointing that Microsoft are pushing it, as it betrays a fatal misunderstanding of what HTML injection is.

Unfortunately disabling it gets more irritating under ASP.NET 4. You have to reset the old model with `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` and then add `ValidateRequest="false"` to the page.

Comment: Thank you. A couple questions. How can I be certain my text is being escaped properly when using the @Html.TextAreaFor() helper? Second, do you have any documentation/references I could read on the bogus-ness of Request Validation? It is presented as pretty solid, but I'd love to learn the innards and perhaps roll my own. Just didn't want to turn it off unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: The MVC HTML helpers do all escape their properties by default, although yes, this isn't brilliantly-documented (and it wasn't always the case during their development!). If you are using ASPX and want to be sure, it is safe to use the auto-escaping `<%:` output syntax to write HTML helpers as well as general escaped text. The helper output doesn't get doubly-escaped because it comes wrapped as an `HtmlString`, which short-circuits the extra escaping step. In Razor, @-output behaves the same.

Comment: As for references specifically on ASP.NET's RV I am having difficulty finding Google results that aren't just me ranting. ;-) The background to understand is outlined well by OWASP's [XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), see in particular the “However, input validation is not a great solution for injection attacks...” explanation.

Comment: Input validation is something that you have to tailor to your expected input data formats if you want it to work well; ASP.NET RV is the dumbest kind of broad-brush approach which will interfere with perfectly good input (as here) whilst not actually protecting you from real attacks that don't happen to match its weakly-drawn “looks a bit like an HTML element” flag.

Comment: Once again, thank you for the added info. I peeked inside the helper last night and noticed that. Couldn't find any documentation myself. I'll have a look at the XSS cheat sheet too as I see how a "broad brush" protection might be a waste of time. Our application is an intranet platform app too so it may be a complete waste of effort.

Comment: I would up-vote your response more if I could. I am aware of this 'functionality' being useless and harmful for years, but I am still sometimes struggling against colleagues fearing to disabling it, just in case some escaping was wrong somewhere... (To me that means they simply do not get the point. Or are too blindly confident in all Microsoft designs and do not even bother to think about this case.)