# Not rendering code in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, rendering

I'm using a textarea to display code (yes, it must be a textarea, no weird alternative) and inside the textarea I've got everything from meta descriptions to favicon links. It's changing the entire site's favicon links to what it says in the textarea! Is there a way of just making the text show up and stopping it from rendering the HTML?

A live example can be found at www.pholiooo.com and here's a shortened example of what I've done.

```
<textarea class="code" name="code" rows="10"><html>
<head>
    <title>%name%</title>
    <meta name="description" content="%bio%">
    <link rel="icon" href="%favicon%">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>%name%</h1>
    <h2>%slogan%</h2>
    <a href="http://dribbble.com/%dribbble_username%">See my work</a>
    <p>%bio%</p>
</body>
</html></textarea>
```

A jQuery snippet would be perfect.

Comment: You need to show a code example.

Comment: It's the yellow textarea at the bottom of this page. http://pholiooo.com

Comment: Are you HTML encoding the code? as in, '<' becomes '&lt;'

Comment: No. Wouldn't that just show up encoded in the textarea though?

Comment: Can you show how you put the text in the box; and can you show a shorter example that still produces the problem? Both are necessary for a "good question" to get a "good answer".

Comment: I think the example given at http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_XMP.html will get you on your way

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502360/html-textarea-tag-how-to-correctly-escape-html-and-javascript-content-displa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML needs to be encoded to ensure that it is displayed within the text area. Given your jQuery requirement I would suspect something like the following would fit the bill:

```
<script>
  var someHtmlString = "<html>...</html>";
  $("textarea.code").text(someHtmlString);
</script>

<textarea class="code" name="code" rows="10"></textarea>
```