# Too many characters in character literal while converting HTML Tag to Entity reference

Tags: html, string, c#-4.0

I have generated an HTML tag through C# code. I am able to render correctly in the text area. When I googled it, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502360/html-textarea-tag-how-to-correctly-escape). To render the HTML tags in the text area, we need to convert the '<','>' into HTML entity references. But when I am trying to replace using `String.Replace`, it throws an error: **Too many characters in character literal**
.

```
string psHtmlOutput="<html><body><table border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3'><tr><th> Name </th><th>DomainName</th><th>DomainType</th><th>Defualt</th></tr><tr><td>india.local</td><td>india.local</td><td>Authoritative</td><td>True</td></tr></table></body></html>";

psHtmlOutput.Replace('>','&gt;');
psHtmlOutput.Replace('<','&lt;');
```

> Error: Too many characters in character literal

Please help; how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String.Replace` method has two overloads:

1. One that operates on `String`s.
2. One that operates on `Char`s.

In C#, single quotation marks are used to specify `Char` literals. Because you have used single quotes, the second overload of the method has been used. However, your second argument is not a valid character literal because *`&gt;`* is not a single character.

So if you actually want to replace the character with a string, just use the overload that takes strings:

```
psHtmlOutput.Replace(">", "&gt;");
psHtmlOutput.Replace("<", "&lt;");
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it converting now. But i am not able to render correctly in the Textarea. It just render just like that.Can please provide information how to proceed with this.

Comment: I think you should post that as a separate question. Make sure to also explain how you're putting the text in the `<textarea>` and what libraries/framework you're using to generate HTML.